# Need help creating a sort of database

Tags: java

So, being new to java, Im not exactly sure how to do this.

We have created a simulator for fun, and it uses a class to create an object.  Two said objects are compared to determine the winner. That works fine.

My issue is that I want to make a database of sorts, that I can store up to 64 of these objects in, and call them into the simulator when I want to.

What is the most efficient way of doing that?

Comment: You should be more specific with how the simulator works, how the objects are created, what do those classes look like. Depending on those things, a DB-like architecture or some other thing may be more convenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either create an *Array* or *ArrayList* of these objects to handle this. If you only want to store 64 objects, I would recommend creating an Array:

```
Object[] obj = new Object[64];
```

You could then write and this to the disk by using the serializable class, ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream.

Comment: Would it be possible to create a method to make them all and then return the array? I'd like to keep it compartmentalized.